# When trying to change username, terminal tells me user is currently used by process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, users

I am trying to change my username, as per advice [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233599/how-to-change-thisnamehostname/233612#233612) however after running the following command:

```
CurrentName@HostName ~ $ sudo usermod -l TheNameIWantToChange -d /home/TheNameIWantToChange -m CurrentName
```

Terminal responds with:

```
CurrentName@HostName ~ $ usermod: user CurrentName is currently used by process 2491
```

And the username stays the same.  Does anybody know how I could fix this and change my username after all?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To quote `man usermod` :

> **CAVEATS**
>
> You must make certain that the named user is not executing any processes when this command is being executed if the user's numerical user ID, the user's name, or the user's home directory is being changed. `usermod` checks this on Linux, but only check if the user is logged in according to `utmp` on other architectures.

So, you need to make sure the user you're renaming is not logged in.

Also, I note you're not running this as `root`. Either run it as `root`, or run with `sudo usermod`.

Comment: if you can't kill the process without it restarting, combine the command e.g. `kill -9 23162 && sudo usermod -l TheNameIWantToChange -d /home/TheNameIWantToChange -m CurrentName`

Comment: The program `usermod` seems to be broken by design. If the user management is done in a LDAP server, changing a user attribute is always possible and does not depend on the running system. I am using Ansible which uses `usermod` and the hole system is unreliable, because changes are blocked by users logged in.

Comment: so uh... how do you change your user id if you're the only account on the system?  i'm assuming the case when you can't log in directly as root (e.g. login is only via ssh) and may have many automatically started processes that you can't kill without losing your connection. @RichardFrank is your solution intended to address this?

Answer (score 8):

Try these steps:

1. Set the password for root user:

   ```
   sudo passwd root
   ```
2. Reboot ubuntu
3. Login as `root` after boot up. This will allow Ubuntu not to generate any process for current user.
4. Change the username

   ```
   usermod -l newuser -d /home/newuser -m olduser
   ```
5. Verify the username has changed by checking the folder name with new username in `/home` directory.

Comment: Is there an option to choose user when doing in this with WSL?

Comment: additionally might need to delete the previous user old directories like `/media/olduser`

Answer (score 6):

Rather than hand-editing the files you know about (bad), or opening up a `root` password (very bad), simply use `at`. Read `man at`, and using the full path for `usermod` (`type -p usermod`):

```
sudo at "now +5 minutes"
your usermod command goes here
^D
```

`^D` is <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>

Then, quickly logoff, wait 7 minutes, and logon.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are running on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux),
open PowerShell as admin and type these commands:

1. Open graphical process manager as root
   to avoid starting normal (non-root) processes:

   ```
   wsl -d distributionname -u root htop
   ```

   Note: change "distributionname" to your target distro, example: ubuntu-20.04.
2. Kill active processes

   After opening htop, you'll see an interface looking like this: 
   [image: htop output] 
   Now choose the process(es) that are not root
   (the ones you want to change username) and
   press <kbd>F9</kbd> to kill those processes. 
   A panel will appear to the left after you press F9; it looks like this: 
   [image: htop with Kill Process (F9) dialog] 
   Choose signal 9, which is SIGKILL. 
   After this there should be no warning
   like "usermod: *user* ... is currently running used by process ..."
3. Change username

   The command below will attempt to change username:

   ```
   wsl -d distributionname -u root usermod -l newusername oldusername
   ```

   Note:
   replace "distributionname" with name of the Linux distro, replace "newusername" with what you want and "oldusername" with current username.

Final result: in my case, I have changed my username from elvisubuntu to ubuntu20.04.

To check username, run:

```
wsl -d distributionname whoami
```

Comment: (1) Note that the question wasn’t actually about WSL. (2) Does it need to be PowerShell?  Wouldn’t Command Prompt be just as good?  (3) In my opinion, making your ***user name*** the same as the *operating system* name is a little peculiar.  (4) Why would you say `-u root whoami`?  Wouldn’t that just say “`root`”?  (5) I deleted your third screenshot because I believe that it doesn’t really contribute to your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you are right, i have removed the `-u root` part

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly a problem with Ubutu where you don't have a root account to login from the first place. So this create a contradiction: I am a user in the sudoer group.  I cannot change my own uid.

Not sure this is the best solution. I first create a fake account foo, add this to the sudo list. Then I login to the foo account and execute usermod -g MYOWNGID mylogin

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should run the command with another user. Login with root, or other user, and try again. If you are in the x window with the user that you want to change, sounds logical that the commands fails.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change the name of the user through which you are currently logged in. You need to switch to another user with the sudo access.

If you don't have any other user and you have already set the password for `root` and you are using **Ubuntu with GUI** (e.g. ubuntu desktop) then you can simply follow these steps

1. press Ctrl + Alt + F5 to switch to a TTY at login screen
2. type the user as `root` and provide the root password which you already set
3. fire this command: `sudo usermod -l <new_user> <old_user>` , please replace <new_user> with the actual new user and <old_user> with the actual old user.
4. press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to switch to a GUI at login screen

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue using usermod, it fixed using the -m parameter, that move the content of the home directory to a new localization.  Use this option in combination with -d (modify the user main directory, where there user ).

I suggest to see the man usermod command

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root, then open terminal and run

```
kill -9 -u [old_username] && username -l [old_username] [new_username]
```

After that run

```
adduser [new_username] sudo
```

to be able to run sudo scripts with the new username.

Comment: The command you are referring to is 'killall', not kill. killall -u <username>.

Comment: kill: invalid argument u

Comment: this works but only with killall

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `new_user` if not other existing user.
2. If you turned on auto login option, you need to disable that option and reboot then login to `new_user` created.
3. Add `new_user` to the `sudoers` file.
4. Now you can use `chmod` from the `new_user` account that you have just created. For example:

   ```
   sudo usermod -l new_username -d /home/new_directory -m old_username
   ```

Answer (score -2):

If you could login with another user, you could use this command to kill all processes owned by that user:

```
sudo pkill -u <username>
```

Then you can run usermod without issue.

Comment: The user wants to change _their own_ username. If they run `pkill -u username` with `sudo` while logged in as `username`, don't you think that would probably cause them to be thrown out of the system? How would that help them?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the step to login as another user first. I edited my answer. @Kusalananda