# Unable to change username ("user <olduser> is currently used by process <number>")

Tags: ubuntu, users

I already read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233614/when-trying-to-change-username-terminal-tells-me-user-is-currently-used-by-proc), but it hasn't helped. Not having logged in to the 'olduser', I type `sudo usermod -l 'newuser' 'olduser'` and it yields the error message from the title of my question.  What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

It is not just being logged in as the `olduser`, but also if the `olduser` id is running any processes on the system. If you search the output of `ps -ef|grep olduser` you may see the processes it is running. Actually, the error message is telling you the `PID` of the process it is running (the `<number>` in your question headline)

You can kill the process or processes it is running and run your change username command and you should be okay. If not, please post what other error(s) you are running into, for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root, then open terminal and run

> **kill -9 -u [old_username] && username -l [old_username] [new_username]**

After that run

> **adduser [new_username] sudo**

to be able to run sudo commands with the new username.